# Angular Firebase - download file from the storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to use firebase storage to download files. I have a realtime database that contains URLs for movies. I have created the service with a method which should download the file. I did everything as in the firebase docs but my method does not do anything.

firebase docs : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?authuser=1#download_data_via_url

my code below:

```
  public downloadMovie() {
    this.fireStorage.storage.refFromURL("https://example_link_for_firebase.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg").getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        const blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open("GET", url);
      xhr.send();
    })
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The method from firebase docs. There are 2 ways to get the reference. By the file name storage.ref() or the url storage.refFromUrl()

Comment: Just to check if the url is correct, and it is. I do not need this console.log

Comment: Please edit your question to include the value of `src`.